# How do I select from a link table, based on a value from another link table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Let say we have the tables

**Student**

```
Id,
Name
```

**ClassRoom**

```
Id,
Room Number
```

**StudentClassRoom**

```
Id
StudentId
ClassRoomId
```

**Homework**

```
Id
Name
```

**StudentHomework**

```
Id
StudentId
HomeworkId
CreatedAt
```

I want to find all the StudentHomework records for all the students I am in a class with.

For example, If there are 4 classes, A, B, C, D. If I am in classes A, B, C, then I want to be able to find all the StudentHomework records where the Student is in the same StudentClassRoom as me.

I have tried

```
            return Context.StudentHomeworks
                .Where(e => e.Student.StudentClassRooms.Select(b => b.Student.Id).Contains(e.Student.Id))
                .OrderByDescending(b => b.CreatedAt)
```

and it's not giving me the results I expect. Can anybody help me with the query that I need? Thanks

Comment: Look at `join` between these classes unless you have set up relationships elsewhere.

Comment: What would I need to join? Which tables? And would it be an inner join or outer join?

Comment: The issue is in this part: Contains(e.Student.Id). You are checking if a student is in his registered class rooms which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AbdullahDibas Oh okay, what should I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that :

```
    var myId = 1111111;

    // first select all ids of student in your class
    var studentInMyClass = Context.StudentClassRooms
        .Where(a => a.StudentId == myId).Select(a => a.StudentId).ToList();

    // then select homeworks of those students
    return studentHomeworks
        .Where(b => studentIdsInMyClass.Contains(b.StudentId))
        .OrderByDescending(b => b.CreatedAt);
```